# Function to create an instance of a class in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a function within VBA to create a new instance of a class I've defined.

The data looks like this:

```
Address 1        | Address 2
123 Sample Ln NW | 1        
123 Sample Ln NW | 2
```

The class has been defined in a class module named "Apt" like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Add1 As String
Public Add2 As String
```

I want to use a function to return an instance of this class (because I have to do it from inside several different subroutines).

```
Sub TestIssue2()

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2

    currApt = makeApt(i)

    MsgBox (currApt.Add1 & ", " & currApt.Add2)

End Sub


Function makeApt(i As Integer) As Object

    Dim x As New Apt
    x.Add1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    x.Add2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value

    makeApt = x

End Function
```

I get:

> "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set".

**What I've tried:**

1. I have found it *does* work if I define instance inside the subroutine, so this does work:

```
Sub TestIssue1()

    Dim i As Integer
     i = 2

    Dim currApt As New Apt
    currApt.Add1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    currApt.Add2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value

    MsgBox (currApt.Add1 & ", " & currApt.Add2)

End Sub
```

2. Searching multiple variations on "use function VBA to create new class instance" led me to sites like [this tutorial](https://analystcave.com/vba-vba-class-tutorial/#Variables_Procedures_and_Functions) or [this tutorial](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/), but both are talking about storing functions inside classes, not using a function to create one.
3. The closest question I could locate on this site is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057670/create-a-new-object-using-the-text-name-of-the-class), where some of the answers seem to indicate what I want is possible.  However, that question asks about a different problem, and doesn't seem to provide an answer to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of small mistakes.  Firstly in TestIssue2() you must define currApt, and then use the `Set` keyword when assigning.  So this becomes:

```
Sub TestIssue2()

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    Dim currApt As Apt

    Set currApt = makeApt(i)

    MsgBox (currApt.Add1 & ", " & currApt.Add2)

End Sub
```

Secondly you should make your makeApt Function return an Apt (rather than an Object), and also use the `Set` keyword.  Like this:

```
Function makeApt(i As Integer) As Apt

    Dim x As New Apt
    x.Add1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    x.Add2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value

    Set makeApt = x

End Function
```

It should now work fine.