# Optional Dependency in VBA Module

Tags: excel, vba, module, compilation, dependencies

## Background

I am developing a VBA module (call it "**`Greg`**") for VBA developers of Excel UDFs.  The purpose of **`Greg`** is to *enhance* the experience for the *end user*, who uses those UDFs in Excel.

The developer must simply copy a snippet into their own module (call it "**`Dev`**").  If **`Greg`** is loaded, the snippet enhances **`Dev`**'s behavior.  Otherwise, it has no impact on behavior, but it *does* prompt the Excel user to import `Greg.bas`.

## Approach

Here is a simplified sketch of `Greg.bas`...

```vb
Attribute VB_Name = "Greg"

' Keep these functions invisible to Excel users.
Option Private Module


' Enhancement function.
Public Function Enhancer(Optional x)
   ' ...
End Function


' Assert the 'Greg' module is loaded.
Public Function IsLoaded() As Boolean
    IsLoaded = True
End Function
```

...and of `Dev.bas`:

```vb
Attribute VB_Name = "Dev"

' Some UDF by the dev.
Public Function DevRegular()
   ' ...
End Function


' #############
' ## Snippet ##
' #############

' Use the enhancer, if available via the 'Greg' module.
Public Function DevEnhanced(Optional x)
    If Enhance_IsSupported() Then
        DevEnhanced = Greg.Enhancer(x)
    Else
        DevEnhanced = DevRegular()
        
        ' Prompt the user to import the enhancer.
        MsgBox "Import the 'Greg' module to enhance your experience."
    End If
End Function


' Check if enhancement is supported via the 'Greg' module.
Private Function Enhance_IsSupported() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Fail
    Enhance_IsSupported = Greg.IsLoaded()
    Exit Function
Fail:
    Enhance_IsSupported = False
End Function
```

## Problem

While this has worked sporadically on Windows, it has often failed there and always on Mac.  The crux seems to be `Enhance_IsSupported()` within **`Dev`**:

```vb
Private Function Enhance_IsSupported() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Fail
    Enhance_IsSupported = Greg.IsLoaded()
    Exit Function
Fail:
    Enhance_IsSupported = False
End Function
```

I assumed that the line `Greg.IsLoaded()` would compile, even if there were no **`Greg`** module present...and it does!  It only fails when a **`Greg`** module *exists without* a member called `IsLoaded()`.

**Unfortunately, it seems that VBA does not reliably refresh its "awareness" of a **`Greg`** module with an `IsLoaded()` function.**

When I import `Greg.bas` and `Dev.bas` *together*, everything works as intended: `Enhance_IsSupported()` returns `True`, and it updates to `False` if **`Greg`** is removed.

But when I first import `Dev.bas` and *run* `DevEnhanced()`, and only *afterwards* import `Greg.bas`, then `Enhance_IsSupported()` apparently returns `False` *despite* the presence of **`Greg`**.

### Note

This latter workflow is absolutely essential: an Excel user must first run `DevEnhanced()` and see the prompt, in order to *know* about `Greg.bas` in the first place!

## Failed Solutions

Unfortunately, no experimentation has availed.  In **`Greg`** itself, I have tried using a constant...

```vb
Public Const IS_LOADED As Boolean = True
```

...and also a procedure:

```vb
Public Function IsLoaded() As Boolean
   IsLoaded = True
End Function
```

In the snippet for **`Dev`**, I have implicitly tried `Application.Evaluate()`...

```vb
Private Function Enhance_IsSupported() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Fail
    Enhance_IsSupported = [Greg.IsLoaded()]
    '                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    '                     Application.Evaluate("Greg.IsLoaded()")
    Exit Function
Fail:
    Enhance_IsSupported = False
End Function
```

...but while this works for `Enhance_IsSupported()` itself, **the same error simply crops up elsewhere** — like whack-a-mole at other instances of `Greg.*` — and **only a manual edit will "refresh" those procedures**.  I would also prefer to avoid unstable calls to any `.Evaluate()` method, even in the `Worksheet` scope.

## Questions

- What is the simplest way to "refresh" the **`Dev`** module, such that its procedures now recognize the calls to `Greg.*`?
- Is this possible without resetting cached or `Static` variables in **`Dev`**?
- Can this be done with an `IS_LOADED` constant rather than an `IsLoaded()` procedure?

### Bonus

- Can this refreshment be done by some `Sub` like `Dev.Refresh()`, called automatically at the start of `Enhance_IsSupported()`?
- Can this refreshment be done by some `Sub` like `Greg.Refresh()`, as run *manually* by the user in the VBA editor?

---

**This project represents a great investment of my time and energy, and it is otherwise operational, so your help is greatly appreciated in conquering this final obstacle!**

Comment: Maybe using a solution using the Microsoft VBA Extensibility 5.3 library. I.e. Use the Extensibity library to search if the module exists etc.

Comment: @M.Johnstone Regarding the Extensibility library, I'd prefer to keep things terminally simple for the Excel user.  Mind you, the **`Dev`** UDFs are what they really want in Excel, so _enhancing_ **`Dev`** should require minimal effort and expertise in VBA.

Comment: Is simply adding it to project references not an option?

Comment: @VictorK _"Is simply adding it to project references not an option?"_  I've lightly explored this, and it would seem the most elegant and user-friendly solution.  **But** when I go to **Tools** » **References...** » **Browse...** in the VBA editor, my only options are `*.olb` and `*.tlb*` and `*.dll`.  How would I make available a **`.bas`** module like `Greg.bas`?

Comment: @Greg I would suggest the following approach ( I use it for all my projects): create an `.xlam` file (Excel add-in) and add `Greg.bas` to that file. Bonus points: save a read-only production version in a place that users can reach, for example on an network drive ([read this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474925/8597922)). Then go to Tools >> Reference >> Browse, change options to `Microsoft Excel Files`, find you `.xlam` file and click `Open`. Once `.xlam` file is added as a reference all of its `Public` functions/classes will be available (with some caveats).

Comment: M.Johnstone advice should really be considered. If I understand, your tool is developed for VBA Developer. There should be no problem for these people to activate the VBE access. From experience, this is no problem, but show, if the access is not set yet. And use of an add-in is also good.
And consider doing it with Excel-Dna and .net and an xll Add-In

Comment: @RedHare _"If I understand, your tool is developed for VBA Developer."_  Almost.  My module ("**`Greg`**") is developed to _enhance_ the Excel user's experience when _using_ the developer's module ("**`Dev`**").  The developer must paste the snippet into **`Dev`** to enable this enhancement.  And the Excel user must import **`Greg`** in order to activate the enhancement, for **`Dev`** along with any other modules enhanced by **`Greg`**.

Comment: @Greg "Is simply adding it to project references not an option?" I like this approach, recently got around to experienting this for utilizing a vba library in other projects.  Appeared to work easily, even the references to type libraries  in the external project appeared to have no issues.   Alternative maybe a project  with a macro that creates a new Excel or Access  project with the required references or check for broken references or import the require modules etc.  Not that  have  tried  that,  should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the reference to the other module is stale. To update it you need the module to recompile.

Based on my experimentations, the VBE won't recompile the code in the module if there were no changes since the last compilation. And as you noticed, importing a VBA module with the manual method (Menu Bar > File > Import File > *Select file in dialog window*), won't trigger a recompilation of the other modules in the project.

[image]

Editing the line with the reference to the optional module (`Greg`) will force a recompilation of that specific function/sub. The function `Enhance_IsSupported()` should then return `True` as expected.

**Adding or removing a member of the module**

Another way of doing it is to add/remove a sub or module level variable/constant which causes the whole module to recompile. Knowing that, you could have a private variable at the top that could be quickly deleted manually to achieve this. Eg.:

```vb
Private DELETE_ME_TO_COMPLETE_GREG_INSTALLATION As Boolean
```

Since your user will be using the VBE to import the module (Greg) manually anyway, it doesn't seem too much to ask them to delete a row at the top of the Dev module.

**Exporting and re-importing the module with stale references**

Exporting the content of the Dev module to a .bas file and re-importing it is another was to force the recompilation and that can also be done manually with the VBE interface.

My initial approach to make this more automated was to just export and re-import the Dev module with a VBA procedure. However this requires the user to have "Trust access to the VBA project object model" (VBOM access) enabled.

I saw in one of your comments that you cannot make the users enable that, so this won't solve your issue, but I'm just going to include the code here in case this is useful to someone.

```vb
Sub ResetModule()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    
        'Optional: Delete all module copies (Dev1, Dev2, etc.)
        On Error Resume Next
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To 100
                .Remove .Item("Dev" & i)
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        Dim ModuleTempLocation As String
        ModuleTempLocation = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Dev.bas"
        
        'Export and remove module
        Dim md As Object 'CodeModule
        Set md = .Item("Dev")
        md.Export ModuleTempLocation
        'Change name to avoid potential naming conflicts
        md.Name = md.Name & "_OLD"
        .Remove md
    
        'Re-import module
        .Import ModuleTempLocation
        Kill ModuleTempLocation
    
    End With

End Sub
```

**Using the Insert File feature**

It turns out that even if the regular *Import file* feature doesn't cause project-wide recompilation, the *Insert File* feature does. This feature can be used while a module is selected in the Project Explorer (make sure the module window is visible by double-clicking it). To use it, go Menu Bar > Insert > File... > *Select file in dialog window*.

[image]

This feature can be used to load content from a .bas file to a module even if it already has some procedures in it. And for some reason, this forces a recompilation of the whole project.

Knowing that you could tell your users to insert a new module, select it and use the *Insert File* feature to insert the content of Greg. This way you'll be sure that Dev will recompile.

Otherwise, you can always let them add the module with the *Import File* method and add a `TriggerRecompilation()` sub to recompile the project using the VBA equivalent of the *Insert File* method.

Basically, calling `.InsertFile` on a Module object seems to be the same as inserting a file from the GUI. It also causes a recompilation of the project and to make use of this, we can create a fictitious `.bas` file; import it; and delete it.

For example:

```vb
Sub TriggerRecompilation()

    'Create fictitious .bas file
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "ForceRecompilation.bas"
    Open FilePath For Output As #1
    Print #1, "Attribute VB_Name = ""ForceRecompilation"""
    Close #1
    
    'Import and delete module
    Dim ThisModule As Module
    Set ThisModule = ThisWorkbook.Modules.Add
    ThisModule.InsertFile FilePath
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisModule.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set ThisModule = Nothing
    Kill FilePath

End Sub
```

There might be a simpler method with VBA to force a recompilation, but that's the only consistent approach I could find that doesn't involve having VBOM access enabled.

Comment: Thank you for all your work and effort on this!  In particular, I appreciate you taking care to address the criteria in my question, and to do so in depth.  I will test your `TriggerRecompilation()` solution very soon, and in the meantime, the manual method is an acceptable fallback solution, whose GUI nature is manageable for even VBA laity: remove **`Dev`**, and opt to export it as `Dev.bas`; then import that `Dev.bas` back into the workbook.

Comment: But `TriggerRecompilation()` _does_ leave me with a burning question: if inserting a new module were enough to trigger recompilation, why doesn't it do so _already_, when one imports `Greg.bas` itself?  Or is that only when `.InsertFile` _specifically_ is used to import it?

Comment: I tested it and it worked!  Quick question though: how might we extend this to Mac?  I suspect `Environ()` and `%TEMP%` only apply to Windows.  If only we could create a phantom file connection and pass it directly to `.InsertFile()`...

Comment: @Greg "why doesn't it do so already, when one imports Greg.bas itself?" -- that's a mystery for me as well.

Comment: _"that's a mystery for me as well."_  I figured it out!  The project only recompiles when a module _already exists_, and new _code_ is inserted _into_ it.  So doing **File** » **Import File...** with `Greg.bas` will _not_ recompile the project.  But if I do **Insert** » **Module**, and immediately do **Insert** » **File...** with `Greg.bas`, then the project _does_ recompile!

Comment: And best of all, this approach **(1)** should be platform _independent_; and **(2)** is entirely GUI and thus more friendly for Excel users.

Comment: Good catch! Yeah, this explanation makes a lot of sense and it's consistent with the beginning of my answer regarding editing existing modules. I'll edit my answer to reflect this new information when I have the time.

Comment: @Greg - Regarding the compatibility with Mac, you could always use `ThisWorkbook.Path` instead of `Environ("TEMP")`. But then you might also want to do `Kill FilePath` at the end of `TriggerRecompilation()` to delete the .bas file as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've got to say, I don't understand how someone could include a reference to a module in their project and forget to include the module itself, so this whole problem doesn't make any sense to me.  But here is a possible solution.  The only problem that I can think of in using this is that it requires a reference to VBA Extensibility.

```
Function ThisProjectIncludesModuleGreg() As Boolean
    'This routine require a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility".
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        For n = 1 To .Count
            With .Item(n)
                If .Type = 1 And .name = "Greg" Then
                    ThisProjectIncludesModuleGreg = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: You don't need the *"VBA Extensibility"*. `With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents` is just fine.

Comment: @JohnWilliams _"I don't understand how someone could include a reference to a module in their project and forget to include the module itself"_.  It's possible I lack some understanding of project management in VBA.  However, the idea is relatively straightforward, and I will set it out in the [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77073837#comment135920268_77100539):

Comment: **(1)** The Excel user wishes to use some **`Dev`** UDFs, so they import `Dev.bas` into the project.  As of now, they remain unaware of **`Greg`**.  **(2)** The Excel user runs `DevEnhanced()`, which defaults to the `DevRegular()` value, and sees the prompt "`Import the 'Greg' module to enhance your experience.`".  **(3)** The Excel user visits the "Greg" repo (on GitHub) to download `Greg.bas`, and imports it into the project.  **(4)** The Excel user runs `DevEnhanced()`, which _should_ now return the value from `Greg.Enhancer()`.  Alas, it errors instead.

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned a constant, why not:

in module Greg:
`Public Const GREG_IS_LOADED = True`

and in module dev:

```
' Use the enhancer, if available via the 'Greg' module.
Public Function DevEnhanced(Optional x)
#If GREG_IS_LOADED Then
    'If Enhance_IsSupported() Then
       DevEnhanced = Greg.Enhancer(x)
#Else
    'Else
       DevEnhanced = DevRegular()
        
       ' Prompt the user to import the enhancer.
       MsgBox "Import the 'Greg' module to enhance your experience."
    'End If
#End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @hennep, thanks for suggesting an answer!  But is this both dynamic and stable?  I don't think the _precompiled_ `#If` will _update_ to the `#Else` once **`Greg`** is imported.  In fact, this seems _less_ dynamic than my current solution, which at least updates at runtime when **`Greg`** is removed.  Furthermore, we cannot _guarantee_ the nonexistence of a clashing `GREG_IS_LOADED` constant in **`Dev`** itself or in a different module entirely.  By contrast, the syntax `Greg.IsLoaded()` or `Greg.IS_LOADED` is entirely unambiguous: a unique member of the **`Greg`** module.

Comment: @Greg That my first idea as well using a compiler constant.  Maybe using the a solution using the Microsoft VBA Extensibility 5.3 library.

Comment: @M.Johnstone Is it really _compilation_ that's the issue?  In my experience, everything _compiles_ just fine, even when **`Greg`** is entirely absent as a module.  My problem is that, when `Greg.bas` is imported _after_ running `Dev.Enhance_IsSupported()`, then the `Greg.*` references do not update.  Nonetheless, when **`Greg`** is initially present, then `Dev.Enhance_IsSupported()` successfully returns `True`, and after **`Greg`** is removed it successfully returns `False`.  So the only issue is "updating" in one direction: when **`Greg`** is initially absent and then imported later.

Comment: @M.Johnstone  Perhaps I should rework **`Greg`** as a _class_, whose objects can be late-bound after construction: first `Set grg = CreateObject("Greg")` and then `grg.Enhancer()`.  Then `Enhance_IsSupported()` will simply test `CreateObject("Greg")` and catch any error as `False`.

Answer (score 0):

I expected the #If-lines to be recompiled after a module was added. Obviously that does not work correctly.

What Office tool are you using?
I've tested the code below in Excel.

```
Public Function IsGregLoaded() As Boolean
    Dim o As Object
    IsGregLoaded = False
    For Each o In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        'Debug.Print o.Type, o.Name
        If o.Name = "Greg" And o.Type = 1 Then
           IsGregLoaded = True
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

In msaccess it would be:

```
    For Each o In Application.CurrentProject.AllModules
        If o.Name = "Greg" And o.Type = 5 Then
```

But in msaccess, both a code module and a class module have type 5

EDITED:

```
Public Function IsGregLoaded()
    IsGregLoaded = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Run "Greg.IsLoaded()"
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
       MsgBox "'Greg' module is present."
       IsGregLoaded = True
    Else
       MsgBox "'Greg' module is NOT present."
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned: this is for Excel.  I _did_ consider the `VBProject` module in the past, but I cannot (and should not) force the user to _fully_ trust the **`Dev`** module, enough to grant it access to the `VBProject` model.  For a programmatic approach, my best bet is probably [late-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233039) with a **`Greg`** object, imported via `Greg.cls`.  **But really, I'm just looking for an easy (manual?) trick in the VBA editor for Excel, which "refreshes" the project to recognize references to `Greg.*`.**  Closing and reopening, perhaps?

Comment: @Greg, With Application.Run there is no syntax check compile time. See the addition in my answer. Normally you'll get an error when the module does not exist.

Comment: _"With Application.Run there is no syntax check compile time. See the addition in my answer."_  I'm afraid I already tried this.  See my **Failed Solutions** section.  While `Enhance_IsSupported()` _itself_ now works, the `DevEnhanced()` function fails.  It fails specifically because `Enhance_IsSupported()` _succeeds_ and returns `True`, and `DevEnhanced()` flows to the conditional where `Greg.Enhancer(x)` then fails—the `Greg.*` syntax has not "refreshed" in _`DevEnhanced()`_.

Comment: _"Normally you'll get an error when the module does not exist."_  My original `Enhance_IsSupported()` accounted for this—and indeed _relied_ on it.  Hence the `On Error GoTo Fail`.  My problem comes when the module _does_ exist, specifically when imported only _after_ `DevEnhanced()` — and by extension `Enhance_IsSupported()` — have already run.

Comment: I see what you mean. Sometimes programs require a restart when settings are changed. I guess this is something similar. Does it resolve the situation when you run the "end" statement in the immediate pane? That clears all memory, unfortunately you cannot use it in a function or it will end the program as well.

Comment: _"Sometimes programs require a restart when settings are changed."_ Bingo. The idea is that, once the user sees `Import the 'Greg' module to enhance your experience.`, they will download and import `Greg.bas` from its repo. Since the import typically requires the VBA editor anyway, then actions like restarting are entirely within their wheelhouse, given the appropriate instructions. _"Does it resolve the situation when you run the "end" statement in the immediate pane?"_ I'll experiment with this. Is there a way to include a `Restart()` procedure in **`Greg`**, which runs the "end" statement?

Comment: And would `Stop` be a [better alternative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/end-statement#remarks) to `End`? _"When executed, the End statement resets all module-level variables and all static local variables in all modules. To preserve the value of these variables, use the Stop statement instead."_  Or would `Stop` properly "refresh" the `Git.*` references in **`Dev`**?

Comment: Stop will only stop execution of the program, like hitting a breakpoint. I have used "End" in a function or sub a long time ago. I can't remember what went wrong but I have never used it since. Keep in mind that the code stops immediately. Not even the "End Sub" will be executed. It is bedtime in my part of the world, have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you, @hennep!  Unfortunately, I tried both `Stop` and `End`, and neither worked.  I even **closed and reopened** the workbook, but it _still_ didn't "refresh" as I hoped.